# How to update one HTML element in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, razor-pages

I have created an image gallery with unite gallery jquery plugin and I would like to change its content(images). So if someone presses an art button function will set new directory path and load images from it. Is it possible or do you have any different ideas on how to do that? Thanks.

```
<div class="galleryDiv">
    <div id="gallery" style="display:none;">
        @{dir = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath(Url.Content(path)));}
        @foreach (var file in dir.GetFiles())
        {

            <img alt="@file.Name" src="@Url.Content(path + file.Name)"
                 data-image="@Url.Content(realImagePath + file.Name)"
                 data-description="@file.Name">
        }
    </div>
</div>

function allBtnClick()
    {
        @{
                setDirectoryPath("~/Content/images/", "~/Content/images/"); }}

@functions
{
DirectoryInfo dir;
string path = "~/Gallery_images/thumbs/";
string realImagePath = "~/Gallery_images/originalImages/";
public void setDirectoryPath(string directoryPath, string realImageDPath)
{
    path = directoryPath;
    realImagePath = realImageDPath;
}
```

1. I emptied DIV
2. I would like to "call" div element again so foreach will create new img elements.

Comment: You will need to write JavaScript to run in the browser to handle when the user clicks on the button. The C# function will only run server-side when the page is first rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Brad Patton, but for some reason, I could not get images from the folder with javascript. In the end, I created bootstrap tabs for every picture section where I loaded images from different folders and then called .unitegallery function for all galleries and it worked! I don't know if there is a better solution but so far so good. Of course, I will be happy if someone finds a better solution and shares it here.

```
<div class="tabbable">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs text-center">
                    <li class="active col-xs-4 col-md-2"><a href="#allImages" data-toggle="tab"><img src="~/Content/images/allWork.svg" class="img=responsive"></a></li>
                    <li class="col-xs-4 col-md-2"><a href="#art" data-toggle="tab"><img src="~/Content/images/art.svg" class="img=responsive"></a></li>
                    <li class="col-xs-4 col-md-2"><a href="#design" data-toggle="tab"><img src="~/Content/images/animations.svg" class="img=responsive"></a></li>
                    <li class="col-xs-4 col-md-2"><a href="#video" data-toggle="tab"><img src="~/Content/images/animations.svg" class="img=responsive"></a></li>
                    <li class="col-xs-4 col-md-2"><a href="#products" data-toggle="tab"><img src="~/Content/images/pictures.svg" class="img=responsive"></a></li>
                    <li class="col-xs-4 col-md-2"><a href="#animations" data-toggle="tab"><img src="~/Content/images/animations.svg" class="img=responsive"></a></li>

                </ul>

                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane active" id="allImages">
                        <div id="gallery" style="display:none;">
                            @{ setDirectoryPath("~/Gallery_images/picture_thumbs/", "~/Gallery_images/pictures/");
                                dir = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath(Url.Content(path)));}
                            @foreach (var file in dir.GetFiles())
                            {
                                <img alt="@file.Name" src="@Url.Content(path + file.Name)"
                                     data-image="@Url.Content(realImagePath + file.Name)"
                                     data-description="@file.Name">
                            }
                            @{ setDirectoryPath("~/Gallery_images/art_thumbs/", "~/Gallery_images/art/");
                                dir = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath(Url.Content(path)));}
                            @foreach (var file in dir.GetFiles())
                            {
                                <img alt="@file.Name" src="@Url.Content(path + file.Name)"
                                     data-image="@Url.Content(realImagePath + file.Name)"
                                     data-description="@file.Name">
                            }
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="art">
                        <div id="gallery1" style="display:none;">
                            @{ setDirectoryPath("~/Gallery_images/art_thumbs/", "~/Gallery_images/art/");
                                dir = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath(Url.Content(path)));}
                            @foreach (var file in dir.GetFiles())
                            {
                                <img alt="@file.Name" src="@Url.Content(path + file.Name)"
                                     data-image="@Url.Content(realImagePath + file.Name)"
                                     data-description="@file.Name">
                            }
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

.
.
.

```
function loadGallery(galleryID) {
$(galleryID).unitegallery({

    gallery_theme: "tiles",
    tiles_type: "nested",
    gallery_width: "100%",              //gallery width
    gallery_min_width: 150, //gallery minimal width when resizing
    gallery_background_color: "#000000",        //set custom background color. If not set it will be taken from css.

});//min columns - for mobile size, for 1 column, type 1
```

[Gallery look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAyNI.jpg)